# Ownership to class instances within closures and referencing from outside

Tags: swift, reference-counting

Suppose I have a Array called `queue` that holds objects of class type Foo, with one item, `fooAh`:

```
Array<Foo>
- 1: fooAh
```

`Foo` has a property for a closure, let's call it `completion`. The closure is of type `() -> Void`. Now, `fooAh`'s concrete implementation of `completion`looks like this:

```
fooAh.completion = {
  print("foo completed, it's time for fooBee")
  var fooBee = Foo()
  foo.completion = { print("foo bee completed too") }
  queue.append(fooBee)
}
```

Then, from somewhere, `fooAh` gets removed from `queue` via `removeFirst`. There's no reference to it from anywhere else so it gets released.
What also gets released with it is `fooBee`, because it was created in the completion closure.

Now, somewhere else someone assums that queue has at least one item at this point. He want's to do something with it and want's to remove it afterwards:

```
queue.removeFirst()
```

The app crashes with

```
fatal error: can't remove first element from an empty collection
```

Is there any way to create a warning that this type of ownership will cause problems later? Is there any kind of assertion I could implement that tells me that the reference are not what they appear to be? Or is my reasoning false somewhere?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Once `fooBee` has been successfully added to the queue, it cannot be "released" out of the queue right underneath you. The queue keeps a strong reference to `fooBee`. Have you confirmed `fooBee` gets added to the queue? Here's my test code: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57d691038922e679d7741a80

Comment: Thanks for the playground, that's really helpful. I found my error and it's rather minor: I called completion without parentheses. That was possible because it was an optional in my implementation and the compiler didn't complain. But that way, completion was never executed. However, the actual problem I derived this example from remains, I have to see how I can change the question to reproduce it. Thanks!